# How to check the version of the python API at compile time from a C extension module?

Tags: python, c

I am writing a python module in C.
The module needs to be compiled for python version 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7.

Now I ran in to the problem that in python 2.5 they defined `Py_ssize_t` for the size of lists, but in 2.4 they just used `int`.

So my question is:
Is there an easy way to check if I'm using the API of version 2.4 or 2.5 at compile time so I can write a little macro?

e.g:

```
#if PY_MINOR < 5
typedef int Py_ssize_t;
#endif
```

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html#module-initialization-and-state which contains an example that works both on Python 2 and Python 3 with ifdefs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [`patchlevel.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/patchlevel.h) in the Python include dir defines what you are looking for:

```
#define PY_MAJOR_VERSION    2
#define PY_MINOR_VERSION    5
#define PY_MICRO_VERSION    2
```

Answer (score 13):

I think what you need is `PY_VERSION_HEX`

there is one line in c code generated by cython

`PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x02040000`

```
#ifndef Py_PYTHON_H
  #error Python headers needed to compile C extensions, please install development version of Python.
#elif PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x02040000
  #error Cython requires Python 2.4+.
#else
```

Answer (score -6):

Just do something similar to this.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (2, 4): //do something, typedef what you need
else // so on
```

Comment: The question asked for C code, this is Python.